# Intuitive UI for first-posts review - ability to select (checkbox) from all current tags

Tags: feature-request

**Current Behavior**

On SO website, the 'Review -> First Posts' interface can be better. 
Currently, a User has to open the Filters and type in the tags to see the related first posts & then select.

This process has to repeated every time you select/ change a new tag/s.

**Proposed Change**

In the new interaction - We give an ability to "select or un-select" the tags from the pool instead of typing and then selecting. This action will refresh the underlying first posts catalog.

On the backend side, pool of tags can be calculated by aggregating the tags on each first posts. If the pool happens to be too large, then we can have a way to personalize it for on load filtering.

**Value Add**

Drive a user to review maximum number of first posts depending on their area of expertise.

Thanks